Can I use decorate parameter in react native 0.7x
I want to use parameter decoration syntax in react native, but it throws an error when running, I searched but still haven't found a solution, My code is as follows
    const IService1 = create_decorator<IService1>('service1');
    interface IService1 {
      readonly _service_brand: undefined;
      c: number;
    }
    class Service1 implements IService1 {
      readonly _service_brand: undefined;
      c = 1;
    }
    class Service1Consumer {
      constructor(@IService1 _service1: IService1) {
        // console.debug(service1.c);
      }
    }
    function App(): React.JSX.Element {
      useEffect(() => {
        const collection = new ServiceCollection();
        const service = new InstantiationService(collection);
        collection.set(IService1, new Service1());
        service.createInstance(Service1Consumer);
      });
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <SafeAreaView />
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }

this is my code, i config babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:@react-native/babel-preset',
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'version': '2023-11' }],
    '@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties',
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};

when i run yarn react-native start --experimental-debugger
error: SyntaxError: C:\mobile\App.tsx: Decorators cannot be used to decorate parameters. (27:14)

  25 | }
  26 | class Service1Consumer {
> 27 |   constructor(@IService1 _service1: IService1) {
     |               ^
  28 |     // console.debug(service1.c);
  29 |   }
  30 | }

